debian/rules hook to incrementally compile kernel after changing source?
I want to make changes to an (in-built) driver in the Ubuntu kernel.  But when I make changes to the source file, fakeroot debian/rules binary does not detect the change or recompile the file.
Is there a debian/rules command/hook to detect a change to the source, recompile only the change and rebuild the kernel image?  Given that it uses make under-the-hood, there must be a way, surely.
What I've done already
I followed the instructions in BuildYourOwnKernel to successfully build, install and boot the kernel version 5.15.0-112-generic.
Then I added a simple pr_info("hello world\n"); in the kernel source file I want to work on.  I saved the file and re-issued fakeroot debian/rules binary.  The command completed successfully, but didn't recompile the changed file.  The compiled object file (efifb.o) was not touched.  I can even delete the object file, re-run the command and it succeeds without rebuilding the object file at all!  So obviously that command doesn't rebuild the image.
I tried fakeroot debian/rules build, but no luck either.
There are lots of AskUbuntu posts asking this question, but no definitive answer about how to use debian/rules to achieve this.

The answer is: don't use debian/rules for kernel development/modding.
In the end I just copied the /boot/config-5.15.0-112-generic file from my running system to .config at the root of the kernel source.  Then it was simply:
make clean
make -j8 bindeb-pkg

Using debian/rules the compile took about 8 hours.  Using this method, a full compile took less than an hour, and an incremental compile took about 15 minutes.  Only use make clean when you want to rebuild everything.
To speed things up, I commented out the building of the debug package in scripts/package/builddeb, as suggested in the comment to this post, because I didn't need it.  I also used ccache.
